# Date difference in RoR 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have 2 dates that is `2011-03-01 00:00:00 UTC` and `2011-03-31 00:00:00 UTC`. When I try to get days between them it returns `2592000.0` Days. Why? It should be 30 days?

To get days between dates I use `-` like `date1 - date2`. How can I get correct difference?

My environment is Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 3.0.3.

---

I retrieve data from db and then do like following:

```
//--some html code
<td>
<%@data.each do |data|%>
   <%=(@data.date1 - @data.date2).to_i%>
<%end%>
</td>
//--some html code
```

The datatype in db is `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2592000 is actually correct.  In seconds.  2592000 seconds is 30 days.  (30 days * 24 hours/day * 60 minutes / hour * 60 seconds / minute = 2592000 seconds).

Cheers!

edit: to convert seconds to days, divide by 24*60*60 or 86400.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(@data.date1 - @data.date2).to_i / 1.day   # 1.day.to_i => 86400
```

or

```
(@data.date1.to_date - @data.date2.to_date).to_i
```

with this conversion, it will work for both Time and DateTime

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'DateTime'

today = DateTime.now
bday = today - 1063 #Date before 1063 days
(today - birthday).to_i # 1063

Now it should be clear. :)
```

Comment: @Ashish: I can't understand your logic. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ashish: When I use `(date1-date2).to_i` it returns `2592000`. Which is not correct.

Comment: Are you using DateTime object?